# Store list of a particular type to shared preference

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I've my list, which I'm getting from the json. So, I want to pass that list through shared preference. But, when I try to use setStringList of shared preference, I'm facing an exception.

```
type 'List<ApprovalStatus>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

And ApprovalStatus is a class, which is defined as:

```
class ApprovalStatus {
  final items;
  final index;
  final approvalStatus;

  ApprovalStatus({this.items, this.index, this.approvalStatus});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "${this.approvalStatus}";
  }
}
```

Can't we use user defined type List to shared preference/ If not, the how can we store the user defined type list using shared preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that you are trying to pass List of ApprovalStatus directly to be saved in shared prefs. It expects a List of String.

Try this:

`prefs.setStringList(approvalList.map((m) => m.toString()).toList());`

Make sure to put some serialization logic in toString so that you can retrieve the data back.

Alternatively, you can directly save the JSON array as a string property in shared prefs.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot store user defined types in the shared preferences directly.

You can serialize them to a string format and store *that*.

You already know how to do that, the most common format is called json.